# How to read CSV correctly - pyspark and a mess data

Tags: pyspark

I tried to read a CSV file with `pyspark` with the following line in it:

```
2100,"Apple Mac Air A1465 11.6"" Laptop - MD/B (Apr, 2014)",Apple MacBook
```

My code for reading:

```py
df = spark.read.options(header='true', inferschema='true').csv(file_path)
```

And the `df` splits the second component at the middle:

```
first component: 2100
second component: "Apple Mac Air A1465 11.6"" Laptop - MD/B (Apr,
Third component: 2014)"
```

Meaning that the second original component was split into two components. 
I tried several more syntaxes (databricks, sql context etc. ) but all had the same result.

What is the reason for that? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of scenarios spark has provided a great solution i.e. escape option.
just add escape =' " ' in options. you will get 3 components as shown below.

```
df= spark.read.options(header='true', inferschema='true',escape='"').csv("file:///home/srikarthik/av.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because file seperator is comma(',').
So write a code such that it will ignore comma when it comes between " and "

otherwise second solution-you read the file as it is without column header.then replace comma with */any other punctuation when it comes bet " ".and then save the file then read using comma as seperator it will work